# How to download readable csv file with R

Tags: r, csv

I tried to download csv file from http://census.ire.org/data/bulkdata.html

I tried this code:

```
download.file("http://censusdata.ire.org/09/all_060_in_09.PCT7.csv")
```

It's works, but I have a csv file made of symbols and not numbers. I can read it from R console, but some files have wrong numbers of column.
Why?

TY

Comment: encoding issue perhaps?

Comment: Try `temp <- tempfile() ; download.file("http://censusdata.ire.org/09/all_060_in_09.PCT7.csv", temp) ; read.csv(temp, fileEncoding = "UTF-8")`

Comment: It don't work with "UTF-8", perhaps with another fileEncoding.

Comment: seems to work for me. ubuntu 14.04 , R3.4.0

Comment: user20650 is giving you solid advice. The issue is that you would typically be using `"UTF-8"` to get past the symbol stuff. I would recommend downloading the file straight from Census and looking at it in Excel to see what is going on, if it opens, resave it and see how it imports from your local drive.

Comment: using 
`read_lines_raw(url("http://censusdata.ire.org/09/all_060_in_09.PCT7.csv"))` shows there are some nulls (bytes with binary 0). This may be encoding, but I am unsure. I save the file, open in an editor (atom) save it. I can thenwith read.csv (as advided by @sconfluentus

Comment: Not sure from that description. Usually Census Bureaus have a data dictionary and a document which tells you how to write fault resistant queries against their reserves. If there is encoding you need to be aware of this document will tell you what it is, then searching the stacks will help you get where you need to be. That is where I would start!

Comment: t's works for the first file all_060_in_09.PC‌​T7.csv, with two identical warning messages: "In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, :invalid or incomplete compressed data". The file is readable correctly by R. With this file (for exemple) the code don't work:"censusdata.ire.org/56/all_040_in_56.P12A.csv";. I can't understand why with some files it works and with others not.

Comment: I got it with download.file("http://censusdata.ire.org/09/all_060_in_09.PC‌​T7.csv", temp, mode = "wb"). Thank You!